# Similar Keras code for a tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The following code is a tensorflow code to create a model. It would be really helpful for me to have the exact alternative keras implementation of this code:

```
logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=-1)
log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)
one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_labels, dtype=tf.float32)
per_example_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs, axis=-1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)
```

Specially i'm confused about loss and optimizer, what kind of loss is used here. Can the following code be an alternative in keras:

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(768,), dtype='float32')
preds = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(sequence_input)
model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into Keras documentation for the same?

Comment: As far as I know in the keras documentation there is no such explanation, I know how to implement keras model, my problem is with tensorflow code.